# Recursive implicit function

Tags: recursion, julia

I'm trying to solve a system of recursive equations. For this, the value `V(m)` is defined to be the solution to an equation like `V(m)==g(V(m))`, where `g` is a known function. How can I define a function in that way?

To be specific, consider the system:

[image: latex rendering of unrendered latex]

In Julia I have:

```
T=4;
beta=.95;
alpha=.3;
gamma=.3;
zeta=.3;

V(m) = m<T ? alpha+beta*V(m+1)+beta*(Z(m+1,1)+Z(m+1,2)+Z(m+1,3)+Z(m+1,4)) : 0.

U(f) = f<T ? gamma+beta*U(f+1)+beta*(Z(1,f+1)+Z(2,f+1)+Z(3,f+1)+Z(4,f+1)) : 0.

Z(m,f) = m<T && f<T ? zeta+beta*(Z(m+1,f+1)+V(m+1)+U(f+1)) : 0.
```

Notice that when computing `V(2)` for example, the rhs also contains `V(2)`. So `V(2)` is the solution to that equation. How can I compute the values of `V`, `U` and `Z` in a setting like this?

Comment: This doesn't seem specific to Julia. How would you solve this in any other programming language?

Comment: Defined like that, your functions are (mutually) recursive.
Recursion is good when the function call graph is a tree -- 
if not, as in the infamous Fibonacci example, the complexity can become exponential.
This can be remedied by using memoization (in Julia, the `Memoize` package).
However, as you notice, your example is even worse than that: the definitions are circular
(for instance, `Z(3,1)` depends on `Z(3,1)`). 
You have a (linear) system of 24 equations with 24 unknowns,
which you can write in matrix form, 
and solve, e.g., with \.

Comment: FYI: I rendered your LaTeX code. If you don't like it feel free to [roll back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876).

Comment: @StefanKarpinski I can do it in Mathematica because I know how to assign the solution to a linear equation to a variable, for example: `Do[Z[m, f] = 
  Z[m, f] /. 
    NSolve[Z[m, 
       f] == \[Zeta] + \[Beta] (Z[m + 1, f + 1] + V[m + 1] + 
          U[f + 1]), Z[m, f], Reals] // First; 
 Print[{m, f}], {m, T - 1, 1, -1}, {f, T - 1, 1, -1}]`. I don't know how to do that in Julia. I switched to Julia looking for speed improvements.